# after_touch callback does not have access to updated attributes of children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I am not sure how to resole the following egg-and-chicken problem.
I have model called `Batch` that touches parent model `Status` on validation - via `before_validation` callback.
In `after_touch` callback in parent model - `Status`, (status has_many batches) - I am checking if all children of `Status` instance are having an attribute set to true.
The Problem that I'm facing is that all of this performed in one database commit, so my child instance of `Batch` that is just about to be updated with the attribute set to true is not persisted and inside `after_touch` callback in parent doesn't respond with true, making all of this failing.

Do you think it is possible to make it work without doing two commits to the database?

And one important information: the attribute I am checking is a virtual attribute, with value assigned in `after_find` callback in the child model (the `Batch`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking I changed logic how my child model update triggers update on `Status`.

Instead of using an `after_touch` callback in parent, I moved all the code to a callback belonging to the `Batch`. I had also to change type of callback being used to `after_save` to have a batch instance persisted to the database before using `self.status.batches` in `after_save` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You can add **validates_associated :batches** in the parent model.
And add a validation in the batch(child) model on save to check that the attribute is true.

Hope i answered clearly.

Thanks